# Showing Checkbox checked in Edit Page (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I want to show selected check-boxes on my edit page here my code this code show all check boxes selected but i need to show only specific selected boxes only ?

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['pkcategoryid'];
    if($id != "")
    {
        $updatetenses = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tensecategory WHERE pkcategoryid = '$id'");
        $updatetense = mysqli_fetch_assoc($updatetenses);
        $id = $updatetense['pkcategoryid'];
        $cat_name = $updatetense['cat_name'];
        $tenid = $updatetense['tenid'];

    }?>

<div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Category Name :</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="span6" name="cat_name" id="cat_name" value="<?php echo $cat_name; ?>" placeholder="Category Name" required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Select Tenses </label>
              <div class="controls controls-row">
                <?php
                $tenses = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from tenses");
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($tenses) > 0)
                    {
                        $i = 1;

                        foreach($tenses as $tens)
                        {
                        $pktenseid = $tens["pktenseid"];
                        $tense_name = $tens["tense_name"];
                ?>
         <div class="span3" style="margin-left:30px;">
         <label class="checkbox-inline">
         <input type="checkbox" name="tenses" value="<?php echo $tens['pktenseid']; ?>" checked = "<?php echo $tens["tense_name"]; ?>"/> <?php echo $tens['tense_name']; ?>

         </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

in checked php line you must check if data checked in database , you check the box
and its better have a status column in database for checked or not
in your code becuse name is valid and true all of your check boxes was checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tenses" value="<?php echo $tens['pktenseid']; ?>" <?php if($tens["status"] != 1){echo "checked";}  ?>> <?php echo $tens['tense_name']; ?>
```

its should be like this
OR
if you want to check specific name you can use this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tenses" value="<?php echo $tens['pktenseid']; ?>" checked = "<?php if($tens['pktenseid'] == "specific_Name"){echo "checked";} ?>"/> <?php echo $tens['tense_name']; ?>
```

Comment: it shows all checked boxes Checked but i want only specfic those user checked ???

Comment: you want to check some of checkboxes right?for that you must code like this

Comment: yes i use your code but it shows all checkboxes CHECKED but i only checked 3 on first row ....

Comment: create Status column in database and with type of int
after when you submit the form you must check its checked or not if checked pass 1 and else pass 2 in query.dont use 0 ,1 its a type juggling

Comment: actually i dont want to add another column in to the table is it possible i use same column to tick (check) only selected checkboxes???

Comment: first explode the checkbox values then echo with id , it will show selected results